# Python index error: How to debug

Tags: python, debugging, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception, jetbrains-ide

I have following code:

```
import csv
import sys

with open('zone1.txt', 'r') as z1:
    zone1 = z1.readlines()

with open('Derived_Dataset.csv', 'r') as ud:
    UMC_Data = ud.readlines()

no_rows = 0

for row1 in zone1:
    for row2 in UMC_Data:
        if row1.split(",")[2] == row2.split(",")[2] and row1.split(",")[3] == row2.split(",")[3]:
            print(row2)
            no_rows = no_rows = 1

print('\n')
print(no_rows)
```

I get the indexerror as follows:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gakadam/PycharmProjects/waferZoning/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    if row1.split(",")[2] == row2.split(",")[2] and row1.split(",")[3] == row2.split(",")[3]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As both files are quite big, usual debug options (JetBrains) are not feasible to use. Is there a debugger which can efficiently help me to narrow down which of the variable(s) goes out of its limits? Thank you.

Comment: Why not printing the results of row<x>.split ... it might give a lot of data, but you only have to look at the last print statements.

Comment: Use `Try` and `except` block it'll not throw the error and pass if indexError comes

Comment: Also, check your .csv file content, it often happens that the last line is empty, hence the IndexError. Another idea is to use Try and Except, like suggested by Ritobroto and print out the line that throws the error, to see what it looks like. It's clear that splitting it does not result in the list you're expecting.

Comment: It was the *.txt file. I used the first solution here, but I will also try writing try-except block. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewrite your for loop as follow :

```
for iIdx1, row1 in enumerate(zone1):
    lsSplitted = row1.split(",")
    assert(len(lsSplitted) >= 4), "Error in row1 line no {} line {}".format(iIdx1, str(row1))
    for iIdx2, row2 in enumerate(UMC_Data):
        lsRow2Splitted row2.split(",")
        assert(len(lsRow2Splitted) >= 4), "Error in row2 line no {} line {}".format(iIdx2, str(row2))
        if (lsSplitted[2] == lsRow2Splitted[2] and 
            lsSplitted[3] == lsRow2Splitted[3]):
            print(row2)
            no_rows = no_rows = 1
```

I think the assertions will help you figure out the lines where index error is coming up.

Comment: This solved it! Actually had an idea where the problem should have been, but something like this will help in future as well. Thank you.